# HTML/CSS Fieldset Legend hidden

Tags: html, css

I have two Fieldsets on my HTML page and unfortunately the Legends are getting hidden. We have an X-UA-Compatible tag that can not be removed...

Please help!

***Screenshot showing hidden legends==>***

[image]

***Desired Result Screenshot==>***

[image]
Here is code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl">
<head>
<META content=IE=EmulateIE7 http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible>
<title></title>
<style>
.GBX_WITH_TITLE {
 border-top: 3px solid #777777;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#ffffff', EndColorStr='#efefef');
}

.GBX_WITH_TITLE .DFGUIGBX {
 /*margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px !important;*/
 position: absolute !important;
 top: -13px !important;
 /*border-top: 1px solid #777777 !important;*/
 padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
 color: #ffffff;
 background: #777777;
 display: inline;
}
</style>
</head>

<BODY>

<FIELDSET id=searchoption1 class=GBX_WITH_TITLE style="HEIGHT: 116px; WIDTH: 979px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 8px; TOP: 74px;">
<LEGEND id=searchoption1Legend class="DFGUIGBX" align=right VALIGN="TOP">Search Options 1
</LEGEND>
</FIELDSET>

<FIELDSET id=searchoption2 class=GBX_WITH_TITLE style="HEIGHT: 116px; WIDTH: 979px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 8px; TOP: 190px;">
<div><LEGEND id=searchoption2Legend class="DFGUIGBX" align=right VALIGN="TOP">Search Options 2
</LEGEND></div>
</FIELDSET>

</BODY>
</html>
```

Comment: the snippet is working as the desired screenshot. my guess is that your fieldset has overflow:hidden;

Comment: Cannot replicate the issue, checked in IE11 (*shudder*) as well.

Comment: Are you sure they're hidden and not displaying outside of your viewport? NVM

Comment: Same here. If I put the contents of the snippet in a HTML file and load it into IE, it gets displayed in emulation mode, and the legends are visible. So... can you post a [mcve] that does demonstrate the issue?

Comment: All I can see from reading up is that filter isn't supported in IE7 at all. Why do you need this to emulate IE7?

Comment: The mentioned syntax fid not work

Comment: @Gezzasa The filter in the snippet is a special MS-only syntax that did work in IE7. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx In fact, this kind of filter works only in emulation mode.

Answer (score -1):

Add below this code in your css Hope It will Work Perfectly.

```
.GBX_WITH_TITLE { overflow:visible }
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that requirement of above working with IE11 and without selecting Compatability mode.

Comment: The above code is the whole html file and screen shots from the IE11with no Compatability mode.

Comment: Unfortunately can't remove X-UA-Compatible tag and the requirement that IE11 users be able to view the page without having to set any Compatability config.

Comment: It's something that just doesn't works fine with IE11 no Compatability mode. Please help